# WPF TransformToAncestor error

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following code

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    ...
    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DataContext is MyViewModel)
        {
            var vm = DataContext as CameraViewModel;
            var p = Parent as FrameworkElement;
            while (!(p is Window))
                p = p.Parent as FrameworkElement;

            vm.GetTransform = () => TransformToAncestor(p);
        }
    }

}
```

And in my viewmodel I have a command handler code, executes when a button in my user control being clicked.

```
public Func<GeneralTransform> GetTransform { private get; set; }
private void OnMyCommand(object parameter){
    var p = GetTransform().Transform(new Point(0,0));
}
```

But the above code does not work, as the `GetTransform()` call says

```
The specified Visual is not an ancestor of this Visual.
```

I think my code above is already ensured that `p` is the window ancestor of the control, but why I still get this error?

Comment: The exception happens in `TransformToAncestor()`, so it's hard for us to determine anything without the source for that. What object instances are the two "Visuals" that the exception is talking about? Is the `p` not a Window instance when `GetTransform()` runs?

Comment: @Jai The code in `UserControl_Loaded` shows that the "this" `Visual` is the user control, and the "specified" `Visual` is the one I track back through ancestor train until I reached a `Window`. This is consistent with observations in debug so I trust the above claim.

Comment: you could try using Application.Current.MainWindow, as it is also the main window of your WPF application, in case you are not running a multi-Window application, and see if that works for your Transform.

Comment: @LupuSilviu We couldn't do this because the "main" window refered by `Application.Current.MainWindow` is a login dialog only. The actual main window will load after the user logged in to the system.

Comment: Your walking up the logical tree and expecting to encounter a visual ancestor. This is usually the case but not always. Perhaps the most notable example of where they differ is with the Popup control, but you could also run into trouble when a ContentPresenter creates a new disjoint logical tree from a DataTemplate. Is there any reason you couldn't use `Window.GetWindow(DependencyObject)`?

Comment: @BrianReichle I have a feeling that what you said is correct for me. But today is Sunday and I am not able to confirm yet. Can you please turn your comment as a proper answer and so once I have the opportunity to confirm I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Firstly, if you have a login dialog, it is probably a good idea to manually set `Application.Current.MainWindow` to the actual main window after the user logs in. Secondly, I find it weird that you are dealing with a lot of visual stuff in your ViewModel when you are using MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Brian Reichle's comment, I figured out the reason and resolved it.

It turn out to be the case that I have the same control in different tabs of a tab control.

As you should know, there is only one tab can be active at all times. Those controls belong to tabs that currently inactive are belong to different visual trees that don't have a window ancestor.

In my case, this is what happened: I track back the logical tree to figure out the `Window` object, but the `this` object is belong to some invisible tabs and don't have that `Window` as its visual ancestor.

Once realized this, the solution is then not to attach `Loaded` event, but attach `IsVisibleChanged` event.

```
    private void UserControl_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, 
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(bool)e.NewValue)
            return;
        if (DataContext is CameraViewModel)
        {
            SaveTransform();
        }
        else Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(SaveTransform);
    }

    private void SaveTransform()
    {
        var vm = DataContext as CameraViewModel;
        var w = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this) as FrameworkElement;
        while (w != null && !(w is Window))
            w = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(w) as FrameworkElement;
        if (w != null)
        {
            vm.GetTransform = () => TransformToAncestor(w);
        }
    }
```

Note: in the first fire of `IsVisibleChanged` event the data context might not being set yet. So the above code have to postpond the `SaveTransform` code later.